# How to serialize foreignkey in Django Rest Framwork?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have jobs model and categories model and they have one to many relationship. so I want to get the details of category as well when i pull the job model.

Abstract Job Model

```
class JobAbstractModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    no_of_vacancy = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    offered_salary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    education_level = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    description_points = models.TextField(blank=True)
    skills = models.TextField()
    other_specification = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Job Model

```
class Job(JobAbstractModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='categories')
    job_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=JOB_LEVEL_CHOICES, default='Mid')
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EMPLOYEMENT_TYPE_CHOICES, default='Full')
    experienced_required = models.FloatField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='jobs_created_by')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Category Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories_images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id + ":"+self.name
```

Serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_image(self, category):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        image_url = category.image.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)


class JobOverViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #category = serializers.CharField(source='category.name', read_only=True)
    categories = CategorySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['id', 'no_of_vacancy', 'employment_type', 'experienced_required', 'categories']
```

jobs.py

```
class JobCategoriesView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        serializer = CategorySerializer(categories, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)


class JobOverView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        jobs = Job.objects.filter(deadline__gte=date.today())
        serializer = JobOverViewSerializer(jobs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The output json is:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Data Retrieved Successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "no_of_vacancy": 1,
            "employment_type": "Full",
            "experienced_required": 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

so, all i am wondering is where is the categories data. I have categories serializer while fetching jobs. so am i doing something wrong that avoids pulling categories data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your model definition, for each `Job` instance, there will be only ***one*** `Category` in the database.

So, change your `JobOverViewSerializer` as

```
class JobOverViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True) # remove `many=True` as well as change the field name to `category`

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [
            'id',
            'no_of_vacancy',
            'employment_type',
            'experienced_required',
            'category' # use `category` instead of `categories`
        ]
```

Comment: thanks it works. but the other issue i get is, the image url. it simply returns json as  {
            "id": 1,
            "no_of_vacancy": 1,
            "employment_type": "Full",
            "experienced_required": 1.0,
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Software Development",
                "is_active": true,
                "image": "/categories_images/software.jpg"
            }
        },  so  image = serializers.SerializerMethodField() says AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'.

Comment: is there any way to pass request object on the context so that serializemethod works ?

Comment: Do you want ***absolute URL***? pass request context to the serialzer as you have done in the `JobCategoriesView`

Answer (score 1):

The serializer is looking for `categories` in the `Job` model. There isn't any field called `categories`, thus there will be no data to be returned.

You need to use `category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True, many=True)` in the serializer. Notice that it's the same you've already done, just that the name is the same as the name of the field in the Job model. Also, in the Meta, you have to modify the last field: `fields = ['id', 'no_of_vacancy', 'employment_type', 'experienced_required', 'category']`.

As a side note, the `category` foreign key field in the `Job` model is not well made. You want its related name to be the name to identify the model in the opposite direction. With your code as an example, if `Job` has a foreign key pointing to `Category`, you want its related name to be `jobs`, because a `Category` can be related to several `Job`s.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your Models definition. Defined like this your Job object has only one category whereas your Category object can have multiple jobs (named illogically "categories"). You should define your models this way:

```
class Job(JobAbstractModel):
    job_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=JOB_LEVEL_CHOICES, default='Mid')
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EMPLOYEMENT_TYPE_CHOICES, default='Full')
    experienced_required = models.FloatField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='jobs_created_by')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='categories')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories_images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id + ":"+self.name
```

Or maybe you would want to use [Many-to-many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) so that one job can have multiple categories and one category can be used for multiple jobs.